# How to get nested data from json object in datatable

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am working on `jQuery datatable` in `mvc`, I get data through ajax call and bind to `datatable` as predefined syntax. The json object for ajax call response contains nested data as shown in picture.

[image]

I did fetch root data successfully, but when i try to get nested data its fail to show the data.

```
oTable =$(".dataTables-example").DataTable({
    stateSave: true,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "ajax": {
        "url": "my_action_method_url",
        "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json"
    },
    pageLength: 10,
    responsive: true,
    "columns": [
        {
            "mData": null,
            mRender: function (data) {
                return data['instituteName']; // working fine.
            }
        },
        {
            "mData": null,
            mRender: function (data) {
                return data['personalInfo.title']; // not working.
            }
        }
    ],
    "serverSide": "true",
    "order": [0, "asc"],
    "processing": "true",
    "language": {
        "processing": "Loading data..."
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know jQuery datatable, but normally in object you can access with `data.instituteName` and `data.personalInfo.title`